# Remote tracking branch in Egit several commits behind

Tags: git, eclipse, egit

I'm new to GIT and use EGit with Eclipse. I try to understand the *Remote Tracking* folder in eGits *Git Repositories* view.
I'm working in a branch who has already been published to the remote repository. I'v made changes which I already pushed to the remote repository. In the *Git Repositories* view the displayed commit id for my branch under *Local* is the last commit id. But when I select the corresponding branch under *Remote Tracking* the commit id is a different one - an older one as shown in the history (See screenshots below). Why is that? I was under the impression this should show the state of the remote repository. This would allow me to see the difference between a branch in local repository and its corresponding remote repository. Or is there a better way to do this with EGit? Is that a normal state of this *Remote Tracking* branch?

History of local branch:
[image: History of local branch]
History of remote branch, several commits behind:
[image]

Comment: If you also used the Git command line, press the Refresh button in Eclipse. Otherwise, you obviously have not pushed the last 5 commits yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was under the impression this should show the state of the remote repository.

It show the state of the remote repository at the time of your last  fetch.

Make sure you do [fetch from Egit your remote repo](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Fetching_from_other_Repositories), and then check the history of the remote tracking branch again: it should be updated (assuming, as commented, that you had pushed your commits).

Comment: I truly forgot to push. I'm so sorry for wasting your time :/

Comment: @peq No problem: that will help others and remind them a tracking branch is a *local* representation of a remote repository branch: if it does not change after a fetch, it means nothing was pushed indeed.